# How to change text of return key and make a Custom UIReturnKeyType

Tags: ios, swift4, uikeyboard, uitextfielddelegate

We have a number of types available for keyboard return buttons in swift 4 like `done`, `yahoo` etc. I want the return key to be `Add` how can I do that? Is there a way to define a custom `UIReturnKeyType` type?

Answer (score 2):

There is **no way** to customize `UIReturnKeyType` in terms of behavior, button text etc.

For your case, **`.go`** or **`.send`** might be appropriate.

You can also put a `UIButton` above the keyboard with the text of your choice.